# Not booting when inserting HDD in another Dell Latitude E6320 laptop

Tags: boot, 18.04, hard-drive, dell, boot-repair

I have a SATA HDD, with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. My former laptop got broken, and I successfully inserted my HDD in a Lenovo laptop.

Now I just got a Dell Latitude E6320 laptop, but when I install my HDD inside, it just hangs on a black window, nothing is happening.

Any idea of what is going on ?

Comment: If very new system you may need 20.04 or even 21.04 & newer kernels to have full support for newest hardware. If UEFI, which all new systems are, then you need to reinstall grub. But you also need to change some UEFI settings. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en  Be sure to boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode and add this, using ppa per second option instructions:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks, I finally reinstalled 20.04.